# What order should one adopt a service/selector/domain/unit of work pattern in a legacy codebase?

Tags: apex, design-patterns

Just inherited a 4 year old Salesforce Apex codebase. I am a first timer to Salesforce at this point but have a lot of dev and architecture experience in other codebases and languages. Team is small. It's me!

In what order should one start to adopt the service/selector/domain/unit of work patterns that I see mentioned. I have the enterprise salesforce book and have been doing the trailheads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Opinion-based here*

First of all, you want to be using the latest edition of Andy Fawcett's book and the latest fflib-apex-common library. The Trailheads are old, still useful, but not current with the repo

I would do it in the following order

- Selectors (wraps SOQL into methods and hence makes them mockable)
- Domain and Trigger handler (you need a trigger handling framework anyway and the fflib ones are perfectly fine)
- Service and Unit of Work - do these together.

Again, refactor/design for mockability so your unit tests can mock services,
units of work, selectors, and less often, domains.  This means using the Application.cls as a factory (or, more sophisticated, the force-di approach for 2GP work)

An alternate approach would be to do one SObject and then convert all the code to domain/trigger handler - service - selector - unit of work with apexmocks to appreciate the full power of the pattern, then move onto other SObjects